# How can I do more than one action with an ng-click in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In my code there is:

```
<button class="btn float-right" data-ng-click="test()">
    Reset
</button>
```

Is it possible for me to fire more than one function when I do a click of the button. If so how should I code that?

Update. I would like to call the `test()` function in the current scope and the `otherTest()` function in the parent scope / controller.

Comment: did you try `data-ng-click="test();test1();test2()"` ?

Comment: `I would like to call the test() function in the current scope and the otherTest() function in the parent scope / controller.` As scope is inherited, you just define `otherTest` in your parent scope and call it in your scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to call the test() function in the current scope and the
>   otherTest() function in the parent scope / controller.

Just define your `ortherTest` in your parent scope. For example:

```
function ParentController($scope){
     $scope.otherTest = function(){

     }
}
```

There are 2 ways to achieve what you want:
You could try:

```
function CurrentController($scope){
     $scope.test = function(){

     }
}

data-ng-click="test();otherTest()"
```

Or:

```
function CurrentController($scope){
     $scope.test = function(){
          $scope.otherTest();
          //Your test code for this function
     }
}

data-ng-click="test()"
```

As scope is inherited, your current scope will inherit the `otherTest` from the parent scope

Answer (score 3):

You should modify your `test` function to incorporate more logic:

```
$scope.test = function(){
    test1();
    test2();
    //...
    testN();
}
```

Comment: Yes but actually I want to call the test function that's in the current scope / controller and the otherTest() function that is in the parent scope / controller. This is why I need to be able to call more than one function. I guess one solution maybe be to code the otherTest() function call in the test() function but it would be more clear if I could call more than one function at the source.